# Matrix minimization problem: Lowest offer for matrix A and B

Tags: matrices, optimization

I have a problem. I have a matrix A and a matrix B. For this I have a offer:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ B = \left( \begin{matrix} 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ Offer= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{matrix} \right) $$

These can be seen as cost matrices. If I now consider the offer, which is (1 2 3 4), I can calculate costs for A and B using the matrices. If we now apply the offer to matrix "A" the procedure is as follows to calculate the cost.

For A:

- First I go to row 1 and select the second element there (in this case the number 2 in the cost matrix A).
- Then in row 2, column 3 (value: 7)
- Then in row 3, column 4 (value: 12)

Then add all values together: 2 + 7 + 12 = 21 for A

For B the following values are calculated: 14 + 11 + 8 = 33

Thus, A and B for the offer (1 2 3 4) result in the total cost of 54 (A and B summed).

Now the problem:

Is there a way to get the best offer for both matrices to obtain the lowest cost according to the above described procedure? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are $A$ and $B$ arbitrary or do you want to solve the problem only for this specific case of matrices?

If you only want a solution for this specific matrices, I would suggest taking the offer $(\begin{array} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{array})$ as we get a total cost of $3\cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 13 = 42$. You won't get lower than that as the lowest sum of $A_{i1}+B_{i1}=14$ for each row $i$, so the minimum price is $4 \cdot 3 = 42$.

Comment: Exactly, A and B can be arbitrary. The problem is the offer must contain unique elements, so an offer `[1,1,1,1]` would not be possible. And the offer is always as long as the matrix has many rows. The matrix always has as many rows as columns.

Comment: At first you can just add $A$ and $B$ beforehand as you would add them later on anyways. Then you're bascially looking for the permutation with the lowest cost.

Comment: Sounds good to me, is there a chance you could show me how to do that? Would be very thankfull!